# JavaScript inside servlet to redirect the page. Is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, redirect, request

I have a general question. I have seen people writing javascript inside Servlet or submission page to redirect the request to another page. Like

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {  
out.println( "<script> location.replace('myPage.jsp'); </script>" );
  }
}
```

My question is, Is it a good practice to write like this(think its not)? If it is not a good practice what is the disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really bad practice, because:

- The client (browser) needs to download the entire page before the redirection is done
- This will not work on browsers where Javascript is turned off
- Not sure about this, but maybe search engines could have problems with this technique

To send a redirect, it is better to use `response.sendRedirect(...)`. This is a HTTP redirect (status code 3xx) which will not need any Javascript and for sure work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Its Not an professional coding way.

In a `Servlet` as in a JSP you can place whatever you'd place (as a String to be sent in the response) in the final `HTML` page that is going to be formed from the `Servlet` or `JSP`.
 Of course for the servlet it will be only a String.

In this String you can place HTML, `Javascript` or whatever you want and it will work in the navigator, but at Java level it's only a String.

Even though we  have an way to that ,try to avoid in most of the cases.

If we do so problems like client side debugging ,and will become more complicated to new developers to see exactly where you are adding this script(if they don't know we can include script in `servlet` as a string)